# Windows 10 Storage Spaces: Proper Procedure to Recover Unlinked Drives

Tags: windows-10, storage-spaces

**Setup**:

- Windows 10 Pro (10.0.17134 Build 17134)
- Fairly standard Dell desktop machine
- C: drive is a single 500GB SSD for operating system and most program executables
- Primary storage is (WAS!) a simple two-drive, two-way mirror Storage Space comprised of two identical 4TB SATA HDDs.

**Background:**

The machine locked up while working on something so I did a hard power-down. Upon rebooting, the Storage Space (which contains most of my user data) was offline due to one of the drives becoming "unlinked".

Space usage was at 95.7%.

I have five blank, 4TB drives that are identical to these two available, and have pulled and cloned the drive that remained linked to one of them. The "unlinked" one can also be read as a standalone drive when hooked up via USB SATA dock.

**Question:**

What is the normal, proper procedure to replace the unlinked drive and get the Storage Space back in action as efficiently as possible?

Comment: I wish this had an answer... I'm essentially looking for the same information.